# PRE code showing as text

Tags: html, pre

I am using the `pre` code to show my code as text on an actual page, inside a textbox (kind of like we do here). It is working except it shows the actual word `<pre>` as part of the code. How do I remove this?

Example:

```
<form>
<textarea name="myTextBox" cols="100" rows="10">

<pre>
<!-- Add this into your Header -->

<style>
body .calculator_external{font-family:"Titillium",Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:300}.calculator_external p{margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px none;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;line-height:1.6em;color:#666}
</style>
</pre>
</textarea>
</form>
```

For example, if I remove the PRE text, it does this:

```
<br />
<!-- Add this into your Header --></p>
<style>
```

Comment: If you just remove the `<pre>` tags, does it still work?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrwBgN?editors=100

Comment: `<pre>` tag is for only `rendering` the output in the given format.
And textarea will not have any rendered tag output, it contains string type of data

Comment: Hmm, thanks all. If I remove the <pre> text though it puts <p></p> into all my line breaks....

Comment: What is putting paragraph tags into what line breaks?

Comment: If you use the single quote to surround your code sample, it'll treat it like a string. Except that the quotes will only replace the <pre> tag. You will need to parse your code block to convert < & > to the &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Drop the <pre> tags and your code will show as text.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean? If I remove the <pre> tag it adds in <p> everytime I have a line break in my code. Which is necessary so that the text isn't all jumbled, but there really should be no <p> there.

Answer (score 1):

Value of ***Textarea*** and ***Textbox*** do not convert html tag to its appropriate outpout.
It will accept html tag as normal string.

Comment: @IVCatalina : was it helpful ?

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense, but i'm not sure what the solution is - to change it to textbox?

Comment: I have updated my question. If I remove the <pre> text it adds in <BR> and <p> characters everywhere.

Comment: Please provide your output by screen-shot

Comment: I can't add an image here. It looks exactly like I put it above.

Comment: I'm doing it in Wordpress, I don't imagine that would make a difference? But maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100110/discussion-between-ali-and-ivcatalina).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    body .calculator_external
    {
        font-family: "Titillium", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300
    }
    .calculator_external p
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px none;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        line-height: 1.6em;
        color: #666
    }
</style>
<form>
    <textarea name="myTextBox" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: But that would add the stylesheet to my actual page, not as text on the actual page? Then the textarea is just empty.

Comment: I think you're missing what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to display the code to the user as text on the page, by placing it inside a text area. Your code gives me an empty textarea box - you have the text sitting outside of it entirely.

Comment: The code is incredibly long (I only have a small portion of it pasted above). So it needs to sit inside a small text area with scroll bars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100112/discussion-between-ali-and-ivcatalina).